# How to change Label.text s on main story board with code?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I want to change the label.text on my story board. The only way I know how to do it now is by clicking the label and on attribute fields change it, or changing it is when a button pressed.

But I want to change the .text on the story board. Sorry for the confusion, see the picture to make it more understandable.

[image: Example pic]

Comment: Connect your label with your code and change it when you want: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: label.text = "new text"

Comment: If you are using tableview, you should set the text in cellForAtIndexPath. Please share the code for cellForAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to add the change code to your viewDidLoad():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    titlebar.text = "New Title"

}
```

Comment: When I do this, when I run the app to my phone it works but on the Xcode program still shows the old name.

Comment: Once you start building in storyboard, it's probably best to continue by using the inspector as you have mentioned.

But if you really want to code it, control click the main.storyboard and 'open as' -> 'source code'

You'll have to search for your original title name in a soup of code, but once you find it you can change it there and it should reflect on your storyboard.

Comment: Yes! this way I was able to do it. But its hard to notice which one is getting change since all of them have .text as Hello.  Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been updated for Swift 4.2

General form of setting and getting attributed string is given below

```
    // create attributed string
let myString = "Swift Attributed String"
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute) 

// set attributed text on a UILabel
myLabel.attributedText = myAttrString
```